Whenever I try to reset password for my org I get the message that the link is expired
Whenever I try to reset password for my org and try to open the link received in outlook.
I get message in Salesforce like this:

When try again get the same message.
How to resolve that?

Does this answer your question? Salesforce password reset link expires immediately upon request

Useful Article: Salesforce 'Reset Password' Link Is Expired

Please follow the below steps:

Copy the URL link, do not click it

In browser console type like below:
window.open(unescape('<copied_url>')

Press enter


